# Is Gelel Stone related to Kaguya?

Tags: naruto

**1. Color consitency**

The Gelel Life Energy has the same colour with pure Kaguya 10 Tail chakra as seen in Ninja Storm 4 used by Obito, Kakashi, and Princess Kaguya herself. Tenseigan Mode Chakra Color is also related to Princess's chakra color and Kishimoto is very consistent with colours.

**2. Hidden pattern**

The Galel Stone pattern resembles 10 Tails of Princess Kaguya 10 Tail Rabbit form.

[image]

Comment: filler is not canon period :x

Comment: But its THE movie not filler. Stuff in movie is still logical not fantasy and behaves according to the shinobi universe

Comment: stuff  not showing in the manga is not canon . . . i think :v

Comment: well fine.. but it still behaves on Naruto Universe unlike normal filler which my be 100% different than real anime

Comment: even the boruto the movie is used as the beginning of boruto manga.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't count

Comment: This movie is not canon. Please consider The Last & Boruto as the only canon movies.